# Cleaning up sloppy code html/css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to tidy up my html, css and javascript. I know that it is sloppy, but I can't fathom a cleaner way to write things. I can see hat there must be tidier ways though.

http://jsfiddle.net/craigzilla/hk8SR/

Any suggestions?

```
#btn1 {
height: 88px;
width: 110px;
float: left;
position: absolute;
}
#btn2 {
height: 88px;
width: 110px;
float: left;
position: absolute;
left: 110px;
}
#btn3 {
height: 88px;
width: 110px;
float: left;
position: absolute;
left: 220px;
}
.rollover1 {
background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/110x88);
height: 88px;
width: 110px;
opacity: 0;
float: left;
}
.rollover2 {
background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/110x88);
height: 88px;
width: 110px;
opacity: 0;
float: left;
}
.rollover3 {
background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/110x88);
height: 88px;
width: 110px;
opacity: 0;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: have you seen jsfiddle Tidy Up button ? Best way is to indent your code.

Comment: Remove duplicate styling for classes/ids by using multiple selectors. Indent code between curly braces.

Comment: Much less code, pretty much same effect: http://jsfiddle.net/NJmUP/

Comment: A little indentation would go a long way here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all, you can assign multiple selectors the same rule. Something like this:

```
.rollover1, .rollover2, .rollover3 {
    background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/110x88);
    height: 88px;
    width: 110px;
    opacity: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

Even better than that, though, you could eliminate the need for .rollover1, 2, and three and just make a .rollover class that you apply to everything.

If you need a different image for each rollover, then this would work:

```
.rollover1, .rollover2, .rollover3 {
    height: 88px;
    width: 110px;
    opacity: 0;
    float: left;
}
.rollover1{
    background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/110x88);
}
.rollover2{
    background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/110x88?2);
 }
```

You can do the same with your IDs.

If you're seriously looking to clean up your styles, look in to "[object oriented CSS](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/)" (Note: I think the name "OOCSS" is HIGHLY misleading, but it is still good practice). Object Oriented CSS, basically changes the approach to writing CSS. Rather than saying "this CSS is for my button that is blue and has a margin of 5px" and outputting code like this:

```
#myBlueButton{
    background-color:#00f;
    margin:5px;
}

<button id="myBlueButton">
```

You write CSS like this:

```
.blue{
    background-color:#00f;
}
.margin5px{
    margin:5px;
}
```

And then your button will look like this:

```
<button class="blue margin5px">
```

This encourages [seperation of concerns](http://viget.com/extend/client-side-separation-of-concerns-are-we-doing-it-wrong) and [symantic classes](http://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/), while reducing your need for IDs and reducing the need for [overly specific CSS selectors](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). It also allows you to easily re-use your CSS styles without having to [repeat yourself](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/dry-principles/).

Even better than OOCSS, though, look in to things like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) Which allow you to write rules that will generate your CSS for you.

Comment: I have to disagree on suggesting using `blue` and `margin5px` as class names, its specifically recommended against by google; http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml#ID_and_class_naming

Comment: Interesting. Keep in mind that those are Google's internal guidelines and not specific recommendations. That's not to say they aren't without merit, however if you're constantly using a 5px margin and don't want to repeat yourself, while you could perhaps name it better, the specific recomendation of separating that rule out is valid, IMHO.

Comment: I understand not wanting to repeat yourself, but what if in the future your boss says "I don't like the navigation being blue, lets go red" and you used your `blue` class for it? You can't change the `.blue` class or everything on your site will go red. You will have to go back and rename all instances of the nav to have a class `.red` instead of `.blue`. Obviously exaggerated, but still something to think about

Answer (score 1):

Rollover1 Rollover2 and Rollover3 are all classes that have the same exact styling which means you only need one rollover class. You can get ride of two of them because they are the same thing.

Example:

```
 .rollover {  // Everytime you need this styling call this class
 background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/110x88);
 height: 88px;
 width: 110px;
 opacity: 0;
 float: left;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think using classes for everything and then position the elements seperately would take the least amount of code.

```
<style>
.btn {
height: 88px;
width: 110px;
float: left;
position: absolute;
}
.rollover {
background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/110x88);
height: 88px;
width: 110px;
opacity: 0;
float: left;
</style>
```

You only need to declare a class once then you can apply it to as many elements as you want; while ids can only be used for one specific element... So if you want to apply similar properties to many things use a class and then use ids for the specific stuff.

So in your html you could use in your button `class="btn"` and in each button to set their similar properties then you can add a different number in a style tag to uniquely position them `style="left:###px;"`. Then use `class="rollover"` on your rollovers.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (better to have all in 'class'):

```
.btn1, .btn2, .btn3, .rollover1, .rollover2, .rollover3 {
width:100px;
height: 88px;
float: left;
}

.btn1, .btn2, .btn3 {position: absolute;}

.rollover1, .rollover2, .rollover3 {opacity: 0;}

.btn2{left: 110px]
.btn3{left: 210px}
```

You can also make .rollover and .btn be in a sprite CSS to **make it one rule(one class call)** and just use `background-position`: [CSS Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Pointing to the question : **Cleaning up sloppy code html/css/javascript**

Related to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086584/online-service-to-cleanup-html-formatting

- For cleaning up your .css : https://csscompressor.net/
- For cleaning up your .js : http://jsbeautifier.org/
- For cleaning up your html : http://infohound.net/tidy/
- For other options about tidy-up tools : https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=html+tidy+online&oq=html+tidy

Carry on